# Using gdb to disassemble program without source code (Binary bomb phase_4)

Tags: assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering

Working on a binary bomb assignment where we are given on object file (no source code) and have to use gdb to determine what the stdin input should be for six functions phase 1 to phase 6. I am currently on phase 4. The disassembly code for phase_4 is below.

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_4:
   0x0000555555555499 <+0>: sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x000055555555549d <+4>: mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x00005555555554a6 <+13>:    mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
   0x00005555555554ab <+18>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x00005555555554ad <+20>:    lea    0x4(%rsp),%rcx
   0x00005555555554b2 <+25>:    mov    %rsp,%rdx
   0x00005555555554b5 <+28>:    lea    0x1999(%rip),%rsi        # 0x555555556e55
   0x00005555555554bc <+35>:    callq  0x555555554f30 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x00005555555554c1 <+40>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
   0x00005555555554c4 <+43>:    jne    0x5555555554cc <phase_4+51>
   0x00005555555554c6 <+45>:    cmpl   $0xe,(%rsp)
   0x00005555555554ca <+49>:    jbe    0x5555555554d1 <phase_4+56>
   0x00005555555554cc <+51>:    callq  0x555555555b10 <explode_bomb>
   0x00005555555554d1 <+56>:    mov    $0xe,%edx
   0x00005555555554d6 <+61>:    mov    $0x0,%esi
   0x00005555555554db <+66>:    mov    (%rsp),%edi
   0x00005555555554de <+69>:    callq  0x55555555545a <func4>
   0x00005555555554e3 <+74>:    cmp    $0x3,%eax
   0x00005555555554e6 <+77>:    jne    0x5555555554ef <phase_4+86>
   0x00005555555554e8 <+79>:    cmpl   $0x3,0x4(%rsp)
   0x00005555555554ed <+84>:    je     0x5555555554f4 <phase_4+91>
   0x00005555555554ef <+86>:    callq  0x555555555b10 <explode_bomb>
   0x00005555555554f4 <+91>:    mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
   0x00005555555554f9 <+96>:    xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000555555555502 <+105>:   jne    0x555555555509 <phase_4+112>
   0x0000555555555504 <+107>:   add    $0x18,%rsp
   0x0000555555555508 <+111>:   retq   
   0x0000555555555509 <+112>:   callq  0x555555554e90 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
```

```
Dump of assembler code for function func4:
   0x000055555555545a <+0>: sub    $0x8,%rsp
   0x000055555555545e <+4>: mov    %edx,%eax
=> 0x0000555555555460 <+6>: sub    %esi,%eax
   0x0000555555555462 <+8>: mov    %eax,%ecx
   0x0000555555555464 <+10>:    shr    $0x1f,%ecx
   0x0000555555555467 <+13>:    add    %eax,%ecx
   0x0000555555555469 <+15>:    sar    %ecx
   0x000055555555546b <+17>:    add    %esi,%ecx
   0x000055555555546d <+19>:    cmp    %edi,%ecx
   0x000055555555546f <+21>:    jg     0x55555555547f <func4+37>
   0x0000555555555471 <+23>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000555555555476 <+28>:    cmp    %edi,%ecx
   0x0000555555555478 <+30>:    jl     0x55555555548b <func4+49>
   0x000055555555547a <+32>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
   0x000055555555547e <+36>:    retq   
   0x000055555555547f <+37>:    lea    -0x1(%rcx),%edx
   0x0000555555555482 <+40>:    callq  0x55555555545a <func4>
   0x0000555555555487 <+45>:    add    %eax,%eax
   0x0000555555555489 <+47>:    jmp    0x55555555547a <func4+32>
   0x000055555555548b <+49>:    lea    0x1(%rcx),%esi
   0x000055555555548e <+52>:    callq  0x55555555545a <func4>
   0x0000555555555493 <+57>:    lea    0x1(%rax,%rax,1),%eax
   0x0000555555555497 <+61>:    jmp    0x55555555547a <func4+32>
End of assembler dump.
```

I know that my input needs to be two integers "%d %d" from lines <+28> to <+40>. My confusion is with func4 on line <+69>. I thought that the function took 3 inputs, %edx = 14 %esi = 0 and %edi which is the first of the two integers from the input. When I display the contents of the register before the function call they are

```
0x00005555555554de in phase_4 ()
1: $eax = 2
2: $edx = 14
3: $esi = 0
```

But when I display them when I step into func4 they change to this.

```
Single stepping until exit from function func4,
which has no line number information.

Breakpoint 2, 0x000055555555545a in func4 ()
1: $eax = 14
2: $edx = 6
3: $esi = 0
```

I know that the output of func4 needs to be equal to 0x3 from line <+74>. I've tried to trace through func4 to find what it does, but I don't know where the 6 comes from (my test inputs were 5 and 3). Can someone help me figure out what func4 does?

Comment: The `6` is not relevant. Well, actually in your case that is an input argument for the next recursion, so it is :) For a moment I thought you were looking at the result.

Comment: Sorry, takes some time for analyzis :) When I was done the question was already closed so I just post my version here: `function recursive(&v, x, y)
{
    t = x + abs(x-y)/2;
    if(t > v) return 2*recursive(v, x, t-1);
    if(t < v) return 2*recursive(v, t+1, y);
    return 0;
}`